# Apple Developer - Provisioning profile showing invalid status

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, warnings, provisioning-profile

I am new in ios, I have created provisioning profile on developer.apple.com more than 6 months ago.

Today I checked profile it showing **invalid status**.

Any suggestion what happing with provisioning profile?

[image: certificate image-1]

[image]

Comment: Check whether the distribution certificate is still valid and not revoked.

Comment: I have added new image @rckoenes, I think do not revoke and it validated. What other cases, I can't figure out.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

May be you added a new device to the mix or updated something else that affects this `mobileprovision`. Click on the `Edit` and just re-generate the `mobileprovision` and the status should then go from `Invalid` to Green dot that is `Valid`

Comment: It happened to distribution profile. Push notification suddenly stopped working. Do I need to do something for the app which is already on appstore?

Comment: If the app was working fine while you submitted to app-store, then nothing to worry about.

Comment: Do you have to use that re-generated provision profile? Or can you continue to use the profile you generated to begin with?

Answer (score 12):

Q: What causes the provisioning profile "Invalid" status? How do I resolve it, and how do I prevent it?

A: The provisioning profile invalid status is caused by changes to the profile’s associated certificate or App ID. Any time an App ID or certificate changes, all profiles that are associated to it are marked Invalid. This does not apply to Xcode's team profiles, but applies to all profiles that Xcode does not manage, specifically, custom development profiles and distribution profiles. This document explains the causes in detail and provides steps to resolve and avoid the profile invalid status.

The provisioning profile lives for 1 year, maybe it expired so simply remove it and make another one with the same certificates, app ids and devices and you can use it without any problem.

If you generate a new provisioning profile, your old installations (store or adhoc) won't be affected

Comment: Part of this is from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1878/_index.html. @Abhi, please always quote properly.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I have changed my `Identifier Name` after creating the provisional profile. That's why it was showing `Invalid`.

I just clicked the provisional profile which was showing `Invalid` and clicked the `Edit` and `Save` button without changing anything. Then it became `Valid` and showed the expiration date. Now I downloaded the new file once again

Comment: haha.. edit, do nothing & then save again.  Makes perfect sense (barf).. works tho; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this today, it was super frustrating. For now, just go into "File" > "Project Settings..." (or in some cases "Workspace Settings...") and then select "Legacy Build System" from the "Build System" dropdown.